# ASP.Net Web APi C# - GetAsync not returning XML response content

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am calling an external service using `GetAsync()` and passing parameters in query string. When i check the content in the response, i don't see anything returned, however it returns `200 OK` and in fiddler it returns me the XML response correctly. I need the XML response to get de-serialize to an C# object and then further save it to DB.

Things tried:

1) Tried this by adding this setting in global- app_start(), It didn't help

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

2) Created an object and tried to sent it via `GetAysnc`, that didn't help either.

```
public class Request
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string XML { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public List<string> ProNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

2) Should i try passing parameters in query string and expect json result? if i add mediatyperformatter to `application/json`?

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetData()
{
    string requestString = "&xml=Y&PRONumber=82040X,03117X";
    string result = "";

    string url = @"http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/servlet?CONTROLLER=com.rdwy.ec.rextracking.http.controller.PublicTrailerHistoryAPIController";
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url+requestString);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ex.Message;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
                        Shipments scp = null;
                        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                        xRoot.ElementName = "Shipment";
                        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shipment), xRoot);

                    using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                    {
                        scp = (Shipments)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    }
```

Model:

```
public class Shipments
    {
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Shipment))]
        public Shipment[] Shipment;
    }

    public class Shipment
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int returnCode { get; set; }
        .................
        ..............
```

**Getting error:**`<SHIPMENTS xmlns=''> was not expected.`

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
WH

Comment: You probably are getting the data in multiple packets and the 200 response is the last packet.  Verify in fiddler that the data is in a previous packet.  If you are still having issues use an IE and manually go to the URL and capture results with fiddler and compare to your C# application.

Comment: Works fine for me.  What are you doing with `response.Content`? You need to call `ReadAsStreamAsync` or one of the other methods,

Comment: @CharlesMager- Tried  but getting error
Errors de-serializing XML: {“<query xmlns=''> was not expected.”}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me  -

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var data = client.GetStringAsync("http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/servlet?CONTROLLER=com.rdwy.ec.rextracking.http.controller.PublicTrailerHistoryAPIController&xml=Y&PRONumber=82040X,03117X").Result;
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shipments));
var t = (Shipments)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(data));


public class Shipment
{
    public string returnCode { get; set; }
    public string returnMessage { get; set; }
    public string freightBillNumber { get; set; }
    //props
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SHIPMENTS")]
public class Shipments
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SHIPMENT")]
    public List<Shipment> SHIPMENT { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

this works as well -

```
var data = client.GetStreamAsync("http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/servlet?CONTROLLER=com.rdwy.ec.rextracking.http.controller.PublicTrailerHistoryAPIController&xml=Y&PRONumber=82040X,03117X").Result;
```

**EDIT**

works as well -

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var data = client.GetAsync("http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/servlet?CONTROLLER=com.rdwy.ec.rextracking.http.controller.PublicTrailerHistoryAPIController&xml=Y&PRONumber=82040X,03117X").Result;

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shipments));
var t = (Shipments)ser.Deserialize(data.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

Comment: It works , but why we should we get the response(xml here) as a string instead of using ReadAsStreamAsync() which reads the response, one line at a time